# Extracting a single file from a zip archive without iterating over the entire name list in Python

Tags: python, zip

I have a zip file with a folder in it, like this:

```
some.zip/
    some_folder/
         some.xml
         ...
```

I am using the [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile) library.
What I want is to open only **some.xml** file, but I don't now the **some_folder** name.
My solution looks like this:

```
    def get_xml(zip_file):
        for filename in zip_file.namelist():
            if filename.endswith('some.xml'):
                return zip_file.open(filename)
```

I would like to know if there is a better solution other than scanning the entire list.

Comment: I was thinking about using ZipFile.namelist(), but I don't want to iterate over the entire list.

Comment: You'll have to; only by listing all filenames can you detect the folder names used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This prints the list of directories inside the `test.zip` file:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile


with ZipFile('test.zip', 'r') as f:
    directories = [item for item in f.namelist() if item.endswith('/')]
    print directories
```

If you know that there is only one directory inside, just take the first item: `directories[0]`.

Comment: There are no entries that end with a slash. Ever. Because there are no directory entries.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is not true. `ZipFile` exposes directory entries as well. For a ZIP containing files `x/y` and `x/z/w`, the expression `[i.filename for i in z.infolist()]` evaluates to `['x/', 'x/y', 'x/z/', 'x/z/w']`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've tested the code before posting - it works.

Comment: You are correct, I am wrong. Mea Culpa. The zip spec is.. unclear on the issue and entries for folders are indeed made.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to get directory that containing `some.xml`?

```
import os
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('a.zip', 'r') as zf:
    for name in zf.namelist():
        if os.path.basename(name) == 'some.xml':
            print os.path.dirname(name)
```